# CURL обрезает параметры запроса

Tags: php, curl

друзья помогите с проблемой , есть созданная ссылка для API запроса но при отправке через CURL входящие $_GET запрос приходит частично , последний параметр description

```
  array(5) {
  ["sum"]=>
  string(32) "fgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfgfg"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(4) "0.01"
  ["cardType"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["currency"]=>
  string(3) "AZN"
  ["description"]=>
  string(5) "Order"
}
```

http://site.loc/api/pay/?sum=166c0be39285392a66c8b5482dcea7f9&amount=0.01&cardType=1¤cy=AZN&description=Order from bank&email=mail@gmail.com&errorUrl=http://site.com/error&key=dfgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdfdsfdf&payFormType=DESKTOP&phone=063000000&successUrl=http://site.com/zakaz-otpravlen/"

то есть тут что-то с пробелами description  может кто подскажет в чем проблема с CURL  ?

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; MyIE2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
```

Comment: В адресе пробел должен быть записать как `%20`. Используйте функцию `urlencode` для кодирования параметров

Comment: как правильно использовать функцию , вернее я уже пробовал как в примере ее использовать но гет запрос у меня также приходит обрезан ?
$ch = curl_init(urldecode ( $url));

Comment: спасибо разобрался

Answer (score 0):

для записи параметров использовал функцию urlencode()

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который у вас получился - а то без него другие участники думают, что это уточнение к вопросу, а не ответ.